# How to create users in json with python and update data

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have made a hangman game in python, and it works perfectly. But I am working on an update to exercise my JSON skills. I am trying to create users which will be done by users entering their name upon entering the game and it will put their name in a library that I already have, along with a win/loss ration for all the games they have played. Every time they play I want it to update their win/loss stats, and if they are a new user I want it to create a new user with their name and store it in a json file to save it for next time the game is launched.

The problem is I don't know how to update user data and make an individual dictionary. I have already tried to find answers on the web, but none were specific enough. My code is below for creating users, the play function is the game that I am linking it to (that works). Please help with any suggestions, answers, or resources that could help me. Also, security is not a worry since it is a personal project that I run on a terminal.

```py
import json
from main import play
from main import game

def get_stored_name():
    filename = 'data.json'
    try:
        with open(filename) as a_obj:
            username = json.load(a_obj)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return username

def get_new_name():
    username = input("What is your name: ")
    filename = 'data.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as a_obj:
        json.dump(username, a_obj)
    return username

def greet_user():
    username = get_stored_name()
    if username:
        print("Welcome back " + username + "!")
        print()
        play()
    else:
        username = get_new_name()
        print("We'll remember you " + username)
        print()
        play()

greet_user()
```